# CSS 3 Panel Liquid layout content spacing

Tags: css, layout, panel, liquid-layout

I have a great working 3 panel liquid layout but I just noticed that a problem with it.

When there is a div with a float:left and another div below with clear:both, all the divs below the cleared div get pushed all the way down to the height of the right column. Sorry is a huge space between Section 1 and Section 2.

You can see the code here.
jsfiddle.net/QbSsb/

Is there a workout to this or a 3 panel liquid layout?

Thanks in advance,
Susan

Comment: you mean that if I pull the window out wide, section 2 aligns at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer is instead of `clear: both;` just use `clear: left;` that's why they have clear left, right and both

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for your clear separator

```
<div style="clear:inherit; padding:20px 0px;"></div>
```